# How to modify flow_from_directory or preprocessing_function in ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

According to the keras docs:

preprocessing_function: function that will be implied on each input. The function will run after the image is resized and augmented. The function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank 3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape.

My numpy tensor is of rank 5 because my input images have 3 dimensions (height, width, depth).

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
label_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_label_generator = label_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory="some_directory",
    target_size=(32, 32, 32),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode=None,
    batch_size=4)
```

When I check the first batch, I get my 5D numpy tensor:

```
first_item = train_image_generator.__getitem__(0)

>>>print('first_item.shape')
(4, 32, 32, 32, 1)
```

Now I first want to do a simple operation on every input image, I also check the input shape by printing it:

```
def some_function(arr):
    print(arr.shape)
    arr += 1
    return arr
```

Here I add this function to my ImageDataGenerator:

```
label_datagen = FixedImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=some_function)
```

This is what I get as input shape

```
(32, 32, 1)
```

which means that it really is limited to rank 3. Any idea how I can modify this so that the input shape is `(32, 32, 32)`?

My goal is to use the `to_categorical` function on every input in the ImageDataGenerator. I cannot simply say `class_mode="categorical"` as I am doing semantic segmentation (not image classification). I know that I could write some custom code for generators for that purpose but I want to know if it would be difficult to modify the keras ImageDataGenerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImageDataGenerator` is a `generator` for images.

This means that in order for this to work your data should be images with 1 (grayscale) or 3 channels (rgb). I think it won't work with your 4-D images (unless depth equals 1 or 3).

Comment: I was afraid to hear that. This means I have to write my custom generator that yields me batches of augmented images and labels. Thank you. Here is a good tutorial for custom generators in keras [link] (https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ImageDataGenerator` like you would normally, but at the last step, instead of passing a `preprocessing_function`, wrap your generator in a generator of your own. By doing this, you get full control over the preprocessing function. This means its output no longer has to have the same shape as the input. Be aware that this wrapper function gets fed batches, not single images.

For example:

```
def preprocess(generator):
  for batch in generator:
    yield batch[:,1:-1,1:-1] # example: crop 1 px of each border
```

Now use `preprocess(label_datagen)` instead. I hope you can use this to circumvent the limitations.